# NopCommerce - Get States by Country and Language

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I have a custom plugin to develop in NopCommerce.
I need to get the list of province/states associated with a country.
I can do this easily with;

```
IList<StateProvince> stateList = _stateProvinceService.GetStateProvincesByCountryId(Country.Id);
```

The problem I have is, when I want to get this list for a specific language... French for example;

```
IList<StateProvince> stateList = _stateProvinceService.GetStateProvincesByCountryId(Country.Id, 2);
```

Where 2 is suposedly the french languageId... But this returns a list of provinces in english...

The GetStateProvincesByCountryId code goes as follows :

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a state/province collection by country identifier
/// </summary>
/// <param name="countryId">Country identifier</param>
/// <param name="languageId">Language identifier. It's used to sort states by localized names (if specified); pass 0 to skip it</param>
/// <param name="showHidden">A value indicating whether to show hidden records</param>
/// <returns>States</returns>
public virtual IList<StateProvince> GetStateProvincesByCountryId(int countryId, int languageId = 0, bool showHidden = false)
{
    string key = string.Format(STATEPROVINCES_ALL_KEY, countryId, languageId, showHidden);
    return _cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
    {
        var query = from sp in _stateProvinceRepository.Table
                    orderby sp.DisplayOrder, sp.Name
                    where sp.CountryId == countryId &&
                    (showHidden || sp.Published)
                    select sp;
        var stateProvinces = query.ToList();

        if (languageId > 0)
        {
            //we should sort states by localized names when they have the same display order
            stateProvinces = stateProvinces
                .OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder)
                .ThenBy(c => c.GetLocalized(x => x.Name, languageId))
                .ToList();
        }
        return stateProvinces;
    });
}
```

What I want to do is find the province Id with a string comparison like this;

```
StateProvince object = stateList.FirstOrDefault(spl => spl.Name == "french province name");
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Why are people downvoting without leaving any comments ?

Comment: You could do a join from state/province table to localized property and filter either by localized name or default name.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not sure about cacheManager. Because we don't have the code inside of it. Try the code with/without it. Anyway, let's say it's working correctly;

I think you are just ordering the list with this;

```
            stateProvinces = stateProvinces
            .OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder)
            .ThenBy(c => c.GetLocalized(x => x.Name, languageId))
```

I suppose, you have to write something like this;

```
where sp.CountryId == countryId && sp.LanguageId == languageId && (showHidden || sp.Published)
```

But if this will not solve your problem, you can write this bad approach;

```
...
                stateProvinces = stateProvinces
                .OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder)
                .ToList();

/* You should seperate this function as well. Because you need to pass province name somehow */
StateProvince stateprov = stateList.FirstOrDefault(spl => spl.Name.GetLocalized(x => x.Name, languageId) == "french province name");
...
```

Why this is bad approach? Getting things like this via magic-string is bad. What about upper-case, lower-case? What about performance ( you are getting whole list, converting to your lang and just take one )? etc. I hope this helps, sorry we don't know actually what's going on there...